# Why do I get a "message was not consumed" for a topic subscription if I'm simply not interested in that specific message

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm using MassTransit with an Azure Service Bus transport.

When I publish messages (pub-sub, to a topic), those services that want to consume these specific messages work fine. But other services that are not interested in a specific message - and thus have no consumer registered for it - error with "The message was not consumed" and a corresponding exception.

So either I am misunderstanding something here about how this is supposed to work; or I'm configuring MassTransit incorrectly.

My services are Azure Functions.
They follow by and large the example in MassTransit's repo, with the exception that I'm using Autofac as a container, but that doesn't play into this.

My Function is defined as follows:

```cs
    public class OnBusNotification
    {
        public const string Topic = "notifications";
        public const string Subscription = "generalSubscription";
        readonly IMessageReceiver _receiver;

        public OnBusNotification(IMessageReceiver receiver) => _receiver = receiver;

        [FunctionName(nameof(OnBusNotification))]
        public Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger(Topic, Subscription)]
            Message message,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            _receiver.Handle(Topic, message, cancellationToken);
    }
```

sending happens like this:

```cs
await context.Publish(new SomeEvent());
```

where context is a `ConsumeContext`.

I got, for example, two messages:

```cs
public class SomeEvent{}
public class AnotherEvent {}
```

Service A registers a Consumer and service B registers a Consumer.

Now when SomeEvent is fired, Service A is fine, but service B throws a `MassTransit.MessageNotConsumedException`. For AnotherEvent, the other way round.

My expectation would be that if I don't register a consumer, it just ignores the messages - after all these are not queue-messages (where it makes sense that not having registered a consumer is a bug), but pub-sub events, so obviously not every service will be interested in every one of them.

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How are those different messages ending up on the same topic? MassTransit creates topic names for messages using the message type, and if you're using MassTransit to publish the events, they shouldn't go to the same topic.

Comment: ah, I think this is a very good hint! I will need a day or so to check on this.